# Calling a method of my class from an action method in view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have created a class where I have a method to make a URL connection and perform some processing. In my view controller I'm sending a message to this method:

```
- (IBAction)loadInfoButton:(id)sender {
     LoadInfo *loadInfo; 
     responseText.text = @"Talking to the server...";
     int ret = [loadInfo talkToServer];
     if(ret==1) 
         responseText.text = @"Connection successful.";
     else
         responseText.text = @"Connection failed.";
}
```

It looks like that the execution does not reach the called method. I kept a NSLog in the method talktoServer and it does not show up. I also made a breakpoint at the line int ret = ... and I was not able to get into the execution of that method. 
I have done calling methods from my customized classes before and such a thing did not happen. I'm fairly new to the iOS development world and appreciate your comment on the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
LoadInfo *loadInfo;
```

creates a pointer, but no object. In addition to the pointer, you must allocate and initialize the object, e.g.

```
LoadInfo *loadInfo = [[LoadInfo alloc] init];
```

Comment: @hsnm A common oversight to make. Best of luck with your app!

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a variable for `loadInfo` but never assigning an instance of the class to it. Try:

```
LoadInfo *loadInfo = [[LoadInfo alloc] init];
```